# Aplicar permissões após executar o comando rsync

Tags: linux

Estou a sincronizar os ficheiros na minha maquina local com o servidor da seguinte forma:

> rsync -avz -e 'ssh' --exclude=temporarios ~/Projects/teste/* root@teste.com:/var/www/

Porém para a aplicação funcionar, tenho que ir ao servidor e dentro da pasta /var/www tenho que modificar as permissões:

> chmod -R 775 *

Após aplicar as permissões a aplicação funciona.

- Por que tenho que aplicar as permissões?
- Por que todas vez que executo o comando rsync tenho que aplicar as permissões no servidor?

Comment: Na origem os arquivos já estão com as permissões corretas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os arquivos não estão com a permissão correta na origem e você estiver utilizando o parâmetro "-a" (inclui preservar permissões) os arquivos chegarão ao destino com a permissão da origem. Para consertar isso adicione "--chmod" na sua linha de comando. Exemplo:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' --chmod=ug=rwx --chmod=o=rx --exclude=temporarios \
~/Projects/teste/* root@teste.com:/var/www/
```